# Laravel Joins - Show all data for same columns, prevent overwrite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 5 joining tables. Out of those 5 tables some tables some have the same column names.

```
public function index() {
   $Users = User::leftJoin('employee', 'users.user_employee_id', 'employee.EMP_ID')
                ->leftJoin('account_executive', 'account_executive.EMP_ID', '=', 'employee.EMP_ID')
                ->leftJoin('independent_sales_rep', 'independent_sales_rep.EMP_ID', '=', 'employee.EMP_ID')
                ->leftJoin('internal_sales_agent', 'internal_sales_agent.EMP_ID', '=', 'employee.EMP_ID'),
                ->whereNotNull('users.user_employee_id')
                ->get();
    return View('adminlte::equipment.salesreps', ['Users' => $Users]);
}
```

For example, account.executive, independent_sales_rep, and internal_sales_agent all three have `EMP_ID`.

How can I retrieve all data besides going column by column writing what I need?

I can use

```
->select('account_executive.EMP_ID as AE_EMP_ID',
                        'independent_sales_rep.EMP_ID as IND_EMP_ID',
                        'internal_sales_agent.EMP_ID as INT_EMP_ID)
```

but it becomes a real drag when you have hundreds of rows you need to retrieve data. I was hoping to use something like:

```
@foreach($Users as $User)
<p> {{ $User->internal_sales_agent.EMP_ID }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Obviously that wouldn't work but is there something similar that would work for lots of columns?

Comment: is it throws any error?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way i can think of doing this is comparing your tables and write down which columns are the same. Then you can do a select query this way:

```
$Users = User::select('users.*', 'e.*', 'ae.*', 'isr.*', 'isa.*', 'users.same_column as user_same_column', 'e.same_column as e.same_column')->
leftJoin('employee as e', 'users.user_employee_id', 'e.EMP_ID')
->leftJoin('account_executive as ae', 'ae.EMP_ID', '=', 'e.EMP_ID')
->leftJoin('independent_sales_rep as isr', 'isr.EMP_ID', '=', 'e.EMP_ID')
->leftJoin('internal_sales_agent as isa', 'isa.EMP_ID', '=', 'e.EMP_ID'),
->whereNotNull('users.user_employee_id')
->get();
```

What i did was give your tables an alias, then on the select i selected all the tables, and only declared the duplicate columns with a unique alias `'users.same_column as user_same_column', 'e.same_column as e.same_column'`

From what i know, mysql doesn't have a prefix for all the columns for each table, but at least this way, you only have to declare the duplicate columns